# Preferred form for Try Catch, Begin Commit Rollback?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Which way is better?

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
   -- Code here
   COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

or

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    -- Code here

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction do not respect `TRY CATCH` boundary. As soon as COMMIT or ROLLBACK is encountered transaction closes no matter transaction was started inside TRY block or outside it.

`Best practice is to keep your transaction as short as posssible. With this rule, I will prefer 2nd approach.`

Awesome article @ [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)...abstract is here

*"..If an error generated in a TRY block causes the state of the current transaction to be invalidated, the transaction is classified as an uncommittable transaction. An error that ordinarily ends a transaction outside a TRY block causes a transaction to enter an uncommittable state when the error occurs inside a TRY block. An uncommittable transaction can only perform read operations or a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION. The transaction cannot execute any Transact-SQL statements that would generate a write operation or a COMMIT TRANSACTION..."*

`In your example 1. There is an issue`

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
   -- Code here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK
END CATCH
COMMIT
```

If an exception occurs inside your try block, transaction will rollback in catch block. After this step COMMIT will trigger an exception saying no open transaction to commit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am moving the Commit to within try block of the 1st option for the sake of readability but am implementing the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY


   -- Do the obvious checks 1st if something isnt correct raise error and
   -- get out of try block, A transaction will never begin 
      IF (Some Condition 1)
       BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Something gone Wrong',16,1)
       END

      IF (Some Condition 2)
       BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Something gone Wrong',16,1)
       END

--if nothing has gone wrong ... 
-- Now open a transaction 

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

   -- Code here

   COMMIT TRANSACTION   --<-- If nothing goes wrong commit
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
 BEGIN
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 END  


    SELECT ERROR_LINE(),
           ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           ..... Other Error fucntion to collect information
           -- about error

END CATCH
```

When the control is in `TRY BLOCK` if everything goes well, i.e Sql server doesnt throw an error or you havent raised an error. Control never enters the `CATCH BLOCK`, so you have to COMMIT Transaction inside you `TRY Block`.